# How to reorder the OFDM index before computing IFFT for CFR?

Tags: signal-analysis, ifft

I used Intel 5300 NIC and the CSI tool to get CFR. I also want to apply for a IFFT to get CIR. **Do I need to rearrange CFR before I apply ifft?**

The OFDM subcarrier indexes (for 20MHz) are:

```
subcarrier_index_L = [-28, -26, -24, -22, -20, -18, -16, -14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, -1]
subcarrier_index_H = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 28]
subcarrier_index = np.array(subcarrier_index_L + subcarrier_index_H)
```

And np.fft.ifft (python package) requires:

- `a[0]` should contain the zero frequency term,
- `a[1:n//2]` should contain the positive-frequency terms,
- `a[n//2 + 1:]` should contain the negative-frequency terms, in
  increasing order starting from the most negative frequency.

What OFDM index should be the zero frequency term? Index -28 or index 0?

What OFDM index should be the positive-frequency terms? Index -26 to -1? or index 1 to 28?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If index 0 corresponds to zero frequency terms, the index for postive_frequency term is 1 to 28, the index for most negative frequency is -28 or -1?

Answer (score 0):

I assume from the final questions asked that this is not specific to any specific Crest Factor Reduction (CFR) algorithm but more about interpreting the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT, which the FFT computes very efficiently) results for any application.

> What OFDM index should be the zero frequency term? Index -28 or index
> 0?

Index 0.

> What OFDM index should be the positive-frequency terms? Index -26 to
> -1? or index 1 to 28?

Index 1 to 28 assuming the total samples in the DFT are greater or equal to $28 *2 + 1$.

In general, see the guide in the graphic below showing the indices and their relationship to positive and negative frequencies for the case when the number of samples in the DFT is odd (case 1) or even (case 2).

[image: DFT]

The DFT results are normally indexed to go from index 0 which is the DC bin (or $f=0$) up to one sample less than $f_s$ which is the sampling rate.
The function `fftshift` in Python's scipy.fft library (and in MATLAB and Octave) reorders this index according to the graphic above extending approximately from $-f_s/2$ to $+f_s/2$, so trying out examples with that function is a good way to confirm understanding.  Also the function scipy.fft.fftfreq(N, T) will return the frequency values associated with the index in the DFT result for an $N$ sample DFT as a sample rate given as $f_s = 1/T$.